# Reported speech long sentence

Tags: reported-speech

I'm having trouble transforming this sentence into reported speech.

> She asked : " What was the last place you went to four days ago with
>   this girl ? "

Following the basic rules, I would say it should be :

> She asked what had been. the last place I had been to four days before
>   with that girl

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you opt for **this girl** or **that girl** would depend on the context. The girl concerned might well still be present when you answered. In that case, she would clearly be **this girl** or simply **the girl**.

Equally, your answer assumes that the **you** in the direct quote refers to yourself and not to a third party, which is likely but not necessary. You could clarify this by making it clear that **she asked me.....**.

I would go along with your answer, possibly with one or two tweaks, as in:

> She asked (me) what the last place was that I had been to with this/that/the girl four days previously/earlier.